# How To Handle Multiple Lines within a Command Block in Terraform

Tags: terraform, heredoc, hcl

I have a task whereby which I have to create a Harness Delegate in Terraform, and it has to be modularized and handled by GitHub Actions. As a result, my main TF is basically trying to tar a file, which makes a `kubernetes-harness-delagate` folder in the modularized directory. However, there are a bunch of commands I basically have to run and one is I have to create the script called `util.sh` and I would really like for the local provisioner to handle it, but Terraform seems to be a stickler for multiple lines. Is there a way to do this all in one command without having to do multiple lines and/or use heredoc syntax?

- [Harness Documentation](https://docs.harness.io/article/up3w9d8zd0-automate-harness-kubernetes-delegate-setup#step_1_download_the_base_delegate)
- [Terraform Language Syntax for Multiple Lines](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/strings)

To be clear I don't want to make any of this in the repo, I want the following block to create it within the `command` section in my `main.tf`:

The following works within my repo and will tar the folder and create it, but I need it to other commands as well and I am trying to figure out how to make it run multiple commands within the one command without splitting out all of the commands.

```
resource "null_resource" "delegate" {
  triggers = {
    cluster_arn = module.primary.cluster_arn
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    interpreter = ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
    #command     = "pwd && ls -la && return 1"
    command     = "tar -xvf harness-delegate-kubernetes.tar"
  }
}
```

I tried the following using `\n` as terraform docs suggest at the end of each line but it still didn't like it and I still get an error:

```
resource "null_resource" "delegate" {
  triggers = {
    cluster_arn = module.primary.cluster_arn
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    interpreter = ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
    #command     = "pwd && ls -la && return 1"
    command     = "tar -xvf harness-delegate-kubernetes.tar \n
                  && cat <<-EOF > util.sh
                  SRC_FILE=harness-delegate.yaml
                  TMP_FILE=harness-delegate.tmp
                  DELEGATE_NAME=$1
                  if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
                    echo "usage utils.sh <name>"
                    exit 0
                  fi
                  DST_FILE=harness-${DELEGATE_NAME}.yaml
                  if [ -f $DST_FILE ]; then
                    echo "File $DST_FILE exists. Exiting..."
                    exit 1
                  fi
                  if [ ! -f ${TMP_FILE} ]; then
                  echo "creating $TMP_FILE"
                  cp $SRC_FILE $TMP_FILE
                  dname=$(sed -n "1,/^.*harness.io.name/s?^.*harness.io/name: ??p" $TMP_FILE)
                  sed -i -e "s/$dname/DELEGATENAME/" $TMP_FILE
                  fi

                  echo "creating $DST_FILE"
                  cp $TMP_FILE $DST_FILE
                  sed -i -e "s/DELEGATENAME/${DELEGATE_NAME}/" $DST_FILE
                  EOF"
  }
}
```

Error Message regarding `multiple lines`:

```
Invalid multi-line string: Quoted strings may not be split over multiple lines. To produce a multi-line string, either use the \n escape to represent a newline character or use the "heredoc" multi-line template syntax.HCL
```

How can I handle multiple commands within 1 command block such that `<all_commands_that_need_to_be_run>` are within the main quoted `command` entry:

```
resource "null_resource" "delegate" {
  triggers = {
    cluster_arn = module.primary.cluster_arn
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    interpreter = ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
    #command     = "pwd && ls -la && return 1"
    command     = "<all_commands_that_need_to_be_run>"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is a way to do it with `heredoc` that allows you to run multiple commands in one command using the `local-exec` provisioner. Though the `Terraform` docs are terrible in telling you how to use it.

Example:

```
resource "null_resource" "delegate" {
  triggers = {
    cluster_arn = module.primary.cluster_arn
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    interpreter = ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
    command = <<EOT
      exec tar -xvf harness-delegate-kubernetes.tar
      exec cp ../../util.sh harness-delegate-kubernetes/
      exec chmod a+x harness-delegate-kubernetes/util.sh
      exec .harness-delegate-kubernetes/util.sh 
    EOT
  }
}
```

Commands:

```
    command = <<EOT
      exec tar -xvf harness-delegate-kubernetes.tar
      exec cp ../../util.sh harness-delegate-kubernetes/
      exec chmod a+x harness-delegate-kubernetes/util.sh
      exec .harness-delegate-kubernetes/util.sh 
    EOT
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to run those commands in a bash script and call it from your `local-exec` provisioner, for readability purposes, e.g.:

```
command = "chmod +x ${path.module}/myscript.sh && ${path.module}/my_script.sh
```